# Understanding garbage collections and generations in dynatrace

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, dynatrace

I have gone through various websites to understand garbage collector and i got some idea about it.Using dynatrace I'm monitoring the performance of a server under load. Can someone explain me what are these metrics we get in dynatrace GC graph.Such as generations,large object heap,GC caused suspension heap,transactions etc as in the attachement.
[image: Garbage collector]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the left side, you have information about the different memory spaces, how big they are and if there was a GC in that space.
Basically if an object survives garbage collections in one space, it gets promoted to the next generation. You also have the large object heap for larger files.

On the left side you have different metrics for the CLR. Some basics like the number of transactions it currently handles, the number of threads and used CPU.

The GC Suspension time shows how much time is spent in GC, so with cleaning up memory and not "actual work". If you have GC suspension of e.g. 30s of a minute interval it means half of the time the CLR is cleaning up memory. This value should not be over 15% constantly.

Comment: thanks for your response.
Can i get any of the website link to get more information about each.

Comment: If you go to community.dynatrace.com you find a lot of information in the documentation and forum. You can also just hit F1 in the client to get the relevant documentation page.